# How to sort dynamically, changing field and direction using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
exports.findall = function(req, res) {  
    var limit1 = req.params.limit;
    var stype=req.params.sorttype;
    var sdir=req.params.sortdirection;
    console.log(stype);
    console.log(sdir);
    test.find().sort({ stype : sdir }).select('_id').select('Name').skip(limit1).limit(100).exec(function(err, results) {
    res.send(results);
    });
};
```

Mongoose sorting changing field and direction dynamically, I have to use the above code for sorting. But the code is not working, the above code cannot change field dynamically, so the response is not correct, please give some solution to solve this problem.
http://localhost:3000/api/test/0/Name/1 
the above link I have to changed Name and direction dynamically, my response is not sorting on the Name field.

Comment: If you're using node.js 4.0 or above, try `.sort({ [stype] : sdir })` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot pass objects like that to sort function. You need to create an object for your use case. A sample code is shown below:

```
var sortObject = {};
var stype = req.params.sorttype;
var sdir = req.params.sortdirection;
sortObject[stype] = sdir;
test.find().sort(sortObject)
```

The above code will let you sort dynamically on any field.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using node v4, you can use the ES6 syntax:

```
   test.find().sort({[stype]: sdir});
```

Comment: In my case I had to put both in brackets:  .sort({[stype]: [sdir]})